# How can I get a view by id from a layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-view

This is the only way I can find but it seems hacky:

```
public View getViewByIdFromLayout(int id) {
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if (v.getId() == id)
            return v;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?  These views were created programmatically, not via xml, and the views' ids will be unique in a given layout but may be reused in other layouts.

Comment: Can't you just hold on to the reference of the view and use it later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use [`findViewById()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29) as long as you've given it an ID. Just make sure to call [`findViewById()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29) on the layout for which the ID *is* unique.

Comment: Argh, my eyes must have glazed over because I looked for that and couldn't find it on the list of methods for layouts.  Maybe I was looking for getViewByID or something.

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
 if (v.getId() == id)
        return v;
```

to

```
 if (v.getId().equals(id))
        return v;
```

Comment: `.equals()` compares `String` values. `==` is the correct operator for comparing `int` equality

Comment: more generally, .equals() compares Objects